# Can I set web link's color?

Tags: javascript, windows-10, xtermjs

I'm using [`xterm.js`](https://xtermjs.org/) in my application. I'd like to have cliackabled and links with a custom color in my terminal. I managed to use [`WebLinksAddon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xterm-addon-web-links) to detect and make links clickable but it didn't seem to support set a custom web link color. How can I archive that using `xterm.js`? if there are not anything externally that could help, maybe I could intercept the text with regex before sending to xterm.js and insert some ASCII escape codes to color it, like`"\x1B[31mhttp://my.link\033[0m` this likely would slow down thing, I guess so I'd like a cleaner approach.

Comment: This is not a powershell question. Tag should be javascript?

Comment: @tonypags yep, I'll edit

Comment: Nope its not possible from the plugin itself. Your idea sounds good, but note that it is involved to get done right - the input stream might be string or utf8 bytes (Uint8Array), so this needs some conditional handling. If you are concerned about input speed, maybe go with utf8 bytes (faster than string input), search for 'http' as sentinel within the byte array, and do the string conversion for deep eval+replacement only for a match (+convert back to utf8 - needed for proper multi-byte continuation). This way chunks without URLs can still flow fast. (Watch out at chunk borders though...)